# Efficient way to find pairs of multiplicative inverses

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

Consider the space $\mathbb{Z}_n$, where $n$ is a reasonably large prime, say, for example, 53. How can I quickly and efficiently write out the multiplicative inverses for each element of $\mathbb{Z}_{53}$? I don't want to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm 26 times (for the 52 total terms in this set). Is there a way to do this that's not just "brute force", so to speak?

To be clear, I want to do this by hand, not using a computer.

Comment: Are you asking for computational purposes or for computing them by hand?

Comment: I want to be able to do this all by hand.

Comment: You might consider using Euler's theorem, i.e. $a^{\phi(m) - 1} \equiv a^{-1} \mod{m}$.

Comment: How about writing out the multiplication table? That only involves about $n(n+1)/2$ additions and occasional subtractions (when you pass from $ij$ to $i(j+1)$ by adding $i$ and find that the result is greater than $n$).

Comment: @RobArthan — I like what you're saying, but I'm not sure I'm quite following. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've written up an answer with an example of what I had in mind. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[a]$ be a residue class modulo the prime $p$ and let $[b] = [a]^{-1}$ be its multiplicative inverse.  You can, for instance, find this inverse using the extended Euclidean algorithm.  Then,
\begin{align*}
[a^2]^{-1} &= [b^2]  \text{,}  \\
[a^3]^{-1} &= [b^3]  \text{,}  \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
So use the slow method to get one result, then go through successive powers to fill in more entries in your table of inverses.  At some point, the powers cycle back, perhaps not filling in the entire table.  Now pick one of the unfilled entries and start this process again.  When you run out of empty entries, hooray!, you're done.

One interesting thing that can happen is that you can in one step work out the inverses of the powers of $[c^2]$.  At a later step, you find you are working out the powers of $[c]$ because every even power is already in your table and every (or possibly most) odd powers are new entries.  (Some entries may already be filled in as members of other cycles.)

As an example, modulo $17$, $[2]^{-1} \cong [9]$, so
\begin{align*}
[2^2]^{-1} \cong [4]^{-1} &\cong [9^2] \cong [13]  \\
[2^3]^{-1} \cong [8]^{-1} &\cong [9\cdot 13] \cong [15]  \\
[2^4]^{-1} \cong [16]^{-1} &\cong [9\cdot 15] \cong [16]  \\
[2^5]^{-1} \cong [15]^{-1} &\cong [9 \cdot 16] \cong [8]  \\
[2^6]^{-1} \cong [13]^{-1} &\cong [9 \cdot 8] \cong [4]  \\
[2^7]^{-1} \cong [9]^{-1} &\cong [9 \cdot 4] \cong [2]  \\
[2^8]^{-1} \cong [1]^{-1} &\cong [9 \cdot 2] \cong [1]  \\
[2^9]^{-1} \cong [2]^{-1} &\text{and we've cycled.}
\end{align*}
Note that $2^8 \cong 1$ was a slightly earlier signal that we were about to cycle.

Notice we got half of the entries for the table.  Now try it with $[3]$ and (I think) get the other half (or go around again with another new starting point).

There is a theoretical idea floating around in the above: [primitive roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).  Pulling a primitive root out of thin air is hard, so here, we just hope that we either picked a primitive root or picked a small power of a primitive root so we can fill in many table entries.  Even if you don't, you get some table entries.

We could probably estimate the expected number of cycles to complete the table, which probably has a leading term of the approximate size $\frac{\varphi(p)}{\varphi(\varphi(p))}$, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), to capture the number of residue classes that are a small power of one of the primitive roots modulo $p$.

Comment: Very elegant, thank you!

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the computational complexity of your method is. I'd be quite surprised if it is better than my simple proposal of calculating the multiplication table (which involves no multiplication, no division and $O(n)^2$ additions and subtractions).

Comment: @RobArthan Your method certainly is great for small values of $n$, but I'm more interested in large prime numbers—in the range between 50 and 150, say—such that writing out a multiplication table, and closely analyzing each element, isn't very practical anymore. That was the whole premise of my question.

Comment: Interesting! As I said, I would be interested to know what the actual computational complexity is. I think it is quite likely that you will spend a lot more time multiplying and dividing using Eric's (very elegant) method than you would just filling out the multiplication table. Perhaps you should try some experiments.

Comment: @Eragon: Well, RobArthan's basic operation, additional and reduction modulo $p$ is easier than my basic operation, (two) multiplication(s) and (two) reduction(s) modulo $p$ with occasional full extended Euclidean algorithm runs.  Without any analysis, I would bet \$0.25 his method takes less CPU time than mine for primes that fit in a 16-bit integer and maybe still for primes that fit in a 32-bit integer.  As part of that same bet, I would expect for titanic primes (say more than 500 decimal digits), the tables of powers would be faster.  I don't have a strong intuition for the crossover.

Comment: @EricTowers: thanks for that. In hand calculation, multiplication and division are much slower than addition and subtraction. I would bet  £1 that my method will be quicker for hand calculation by average mathematicians for $n < 25$ and slower for $n > 200$. And I don't have a strong intuition for the crossover in that case either.  $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: If you are interested in computational complexity, I posted an answer with an algorithm that is linear time (for a computer).

Answer (score 3):

Find a primitive root (test the small primes) and enumerate its powers. The inverses are the pairs of exponents totalling $p-1$.

For example, for $p=53$, $2$ is a primitive root, so the powers of $2\bmod 53$ visit all residue classes and $2^{k}$ and $2^{52-k}$ are inverses.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea that might not be an iron-clad algorithm, but for numbers that you'd be willing to try by hand might be useful in practice.

Note that $53+1=54$ has several factorizations: $54=2\cdot27=3\cdot18=6\cdot9$. Since $54\equiv1\pmod{53}$, this instantly tells us that $2^{-1}\equiv27\pmod{53}$, $3^{-1}\equiv18\pmod{53}$, and $6^{-1}\equiv9\pmod{53}$. Note that the last of these congruences follows from the first two, since $2\cdot3=6$ and $27\cdot18=504\equiv9\pmod{53}$. And indeed we can use $2^{-1}\equiv27\pmod{53}$ and $3^{-1}\equiv18\pmod{53}$ to find $4^{-1}$, $8^{-1}$, $9^{-1}$ (which we already have), $12^{-1}$, $16^{-1}$, and so on.

Along the way we might stumble across more elements with small inverses, such as $32^{-1}\equiv5\pmod{53}$. Then we know that $5^{-1}\equiv32\pmod{53}$ as well, which allows us to calculate things like $10^{-1}$, $15^{-1}$, $20^{-1}$, $25^{-1}$, and so on.

We can also look at other multiples of $53$. For example, $160=3\cdot53+1\equiv1\pmod{53}$, and therefore any factorization of $160$ gives us an inverse pair as well. For instance, $8\cdot20=160$, and therefore $8^{-1}\equiv20\pmod{53}$ and vice versa. Similarly, $7\cdot31=213=4\cdot53+1\equiv1\pmod{53}$, and therefore $7^{-1}\equiv31\pmod{53}$.

Comment: Yeah, I was toying around with this kind of thing, myself. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, it isn't too tedious to write out the multiplication table. E.g. let $n = 5$. Then the multiplication table is
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 &1&2&3&4\\\hline
1&1&2&3&4\\
2&2&4&1&3\\
3&3&1&4&2\\
4&4&3&2&1
\end{array}
$$
To calculate the $i$-th row, you just start with $i$, and then add $i$ to the previous element in the row and subtract $5$ if the result exceeds $5$. Then you can read off the inverse of $i$ by looking for the $j$ that gives you $ij=1$. If you really only care about the inverses, you can stop calculating along each row once you get to the entry $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a well-known algorithm in competition programming for listing all multiplicative inverses mod p in linear time complexity (for a computer assuming fixed word size, that is all operations like division and mod on):

Let $\%$ be the modulo operation and let $a[1:p]$ be an array holding the multiplicative inverses. Then $a[1] = 1$, and for $i = 2, \dots, p-1$,

$$a[i] = p - (\lfloor p/i \rfloor \times a[p \% i]) \% p $$

Proof: $p\%i = p - \lfloor p/i \rfloor \times i = - \lfloor p/i \rfloor \times i \pmod p $, then divide by $i \times (p\%i)$ to get $a[i] = - \lfloor p/i \rfloor \times a[p \% i] \pmod p$.

Source: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/module-inverse.html#toc-tgt-3,  http://e-maxx.ru/algo/reverse_element (in Russian)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I missed that you wanted every element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$; I'm sure there's a faster way than this for that application.

I  will expand on my comment; Euler's theorem states that
$$
a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m
$$
where a is coprime to m and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function. Suppose m is the prime you speak of, then notice that $\phi(m) = m-1$. So then we find that:
$$
a^{m-1}  \equiv 1 \mod{m} \implies a^{m-2} \equiv a^{-1} \mod{m}
$$
Therefore, if we take $m = 53$, as in your example, computing the multiplicative inverse is as simple as computing $a^{51}$, which can vary from being very easy (say if $a = 2$), to very bad (say if $a = 51$).

Comment: I think the OP wants to tabulate the inverses of all the elements.

Comment: Yes, this is great, but I'm more interested in tabulating, as Rob said.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh, hm, you're right. I missed that portion of the question.

Comment: the exponentiation can be done in $\log m$ time using exponentiation by squaring. Doing this for all $m$ values takes $O(m \log m)$ time.